# Alarm not going off when app killed

Tags: java, android

How am I supposed to implement an alarm to open the dismiss/snooze screen after the app is destroyed? My alarm works perfectly fine as long as the app stays up, here's how I schedule the alarm:

```
//instantiate calendar to call alarm on time match
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());

//if time is set earlier than current (e.g set for 6:59pm, currently 7pm), do not play until next clock cycle/day
if(calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

//cancel any currently pending intents if toggle button is toggled on
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();

//add parameters to pass to activities that play the alarm
myIntent.putExtra("stream",stream);
myIntent.putExtra("seconds",snoozeSeconds);
myIntent.putExtra("link",ytLink);

//create pending intent to broadcast to activity that plays the alarm
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

And I use a receiver that's fairly simple:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    //....
    MainActivity.ringtone.play();
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(alarmIntent); //start dismiss screen
```

Comment: Maybe you write in your Activity onDestroy() anything like `.ringtone.stop()`?

Comment: I would guess that the `MainActivity.ringtone.play()` call is throwing an Exception. Check your logcat. Also, starting an `Activity` on the Receiver's `Context` parameter requires the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question, This is what i understand, Let me know if misunderstand your question

if you want to open/active your alaram after App close or device reboot
then you have add intent filter android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED in your AlarmReceiver AndroidManifest.xml and you can manage the actions on your AlarmReceiver onReceive methond

Please check the following code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if(intent == null){
return;
}
String action = intent.getAction();
if (action != null && action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
}

AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

}
```

Add intent filter actions in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<receiver android:name="com.monster.android.Services.AlarmReceiver"
android:enabled="false">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use stopService() method:

```
 stopService(new Intent(MainMenu.this, AlarmActivity.class));
```